# SQL - Select values to become column values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been through a few jobs, and I often see databases like this:

```
            Column_Values
            +------+--------------+--------------+
            |  id  |   field_id   |    label     |
            +------------------------------------+
            |  1   |  first_name  |  First Name  +-----------------+
            |  2   |  last_name   |  Last Name   +-----------------------+
            |      |              |              |                 |     |
            |      |              |              |                 |     |
            |      |              |              |                 |     |
            +------+--------------+--------------+                 |     |
                                                                   |     |
            User Row                                               |     |
            +-------+                                              |     |
            |  id   |                                              |     |
            +-------+                                              |     |
+-----------+ 9000  |                                              |     |
|           | 10000 |                                              |     |
|           |       |                                              |     |
|           |       |                                              |     |
|           |       |                                              |     |
|           +-------+                                              |     |
|                                                                  |     |
|           Mapping Table                                          |     |
|           +------------+-------------+---------+                 |     |
|           |  User_Id   |  Field ID   |  Value  |                 |     |
|           +------------------------------------+                 |     |
+----------->    9000    |     1       |  John   <-----------------+     |
            |    9000    |     2       |   Doe   <-----------------------+
            +------------+-------------+---------+
```

Instead of actually have a column where there is a `first_name`, and a `last_name`, the name of the column is actually stored in another table.

How do I select the user, so that I get something like?

```
+---------+-------------+-----------+
| User_ID | First Name  | Last Name |
+-----------------------------------+
| 9000    |  John       |   Doe     |
|         |             |           |
+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

Also is there a name for this type of database? It seems the logic behind this is to have dynamic columns, however I think the issue can be mitigated with a planned downtime to update the tables.

Comment: I've met similar DB design several times. One of the reasons for this was some super-generic form framework which helped non-technical staff to create their own forms in the software, but the price for it was that you've had all the values from all the forms stored as key-value pair in one table, because on background all was powered by the same generic-form piece of code where it does not really matter if the form is related to user or order or whatever. My experience

Comment: @Emil Thanks for the insight. I wish there was a better DB design that is suited for this. MongoDB (No-SQL) or another kind of DB that provides online DB modifications sounds like a better solution.

Comment: It's called an entity attribute value model, or EAV

Comment: @user1157751 . . . The purpose?  To keep consultants employed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cv.field_id = 'first_name' THEN m.value END) first_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cv.field_id = 'last_name' THEN m.value END) last_name
FROM user u
INNER JOIN mapping m ON m.user_id = u.id 
INNER JOIN Column_Values cv ON cv.id = m.field_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

NB: if all you need is the user id and its first and last name, then you don't need to bring in the `user` table. Just:

```
SELECT
    m.user_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cv.field_id = 'first_name' THEN m.value END) first_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cv.field_id = 'last_name' THEN m.value END) last_name
FROM mapping m ON 
INNER JOIN Column_Values cv ON cv.id = m.field_id
GROUP BY m.user_id
```

Comment: There are hundreds of field_id, is there some sort of way to dynamically create the select case?

Comment: @user1157751: a SQL query must return a *fixed* set of columns... You would need to use *dynamic SQL* for this... Or you can use a tool of your choice to generate a serires of `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Sounds like an extremely hard to maintain SQL code. I think I will just generate a series of case expressions.

Comment: @GMB Can you provide an example of making this dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
select 
  User_ID, 
  max(FirstName) FirstName, 
  max(LastName) LastName
from 
(
  select 
    User_ID,
    case when c.Field_Id= 'first_name' then Value end as FirstName,
    case when c.Field_Id = 'last_name' then Value end as LastName    
  from Column_Values c
  inner join MappingTable m
    on c.Id = m.FieldId
) t
group by
  User_ID
```